# Bootstrap 4 alpha5 carousel fade

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Good Day, Trying to get carousel fade transition to work. Any help will be appreciated. Here is code that I have so far.

Boot version: 4, alpha 5

Boot includes between header tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="boot/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="boot/css/bootstrap-flex.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="boot/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="boot/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
```

Custom css between header and after above boot includes. I know (Important) is likely not necessary, but i am running out of options.

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity !important;
  transition-property: opacity !important;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0 !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

Now this is my not working carusel.

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="images/img1.png" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="images/img2.png" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now my boot includes before end of body tag:

```
<!-- Boot Includes -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="boot/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

JS for slideshow

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 9000,
  pause: false
})
```

If all fails, please recommend a simple java slider. I just want plain and simple image transition with fade effect. No need for any controls or sub titles.

Answer (score 4):

See the below example.

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 3000,
  pause: false
});
```

```css
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .carousel-item {
 -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
 -moz-transition-property: opacity;
 -o-transition-property: opacity;
 -ms-transition-property: opacity;
 transition-property: opacity;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .carousel-item,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
 opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
 opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
 left: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="carousel slide carousel-fade" id="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="width:100%;height:400px;background:red;"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="width:100%;height:400px;background:blue;"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="width:100%;height:400px;background:green;"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="width:100%;height:400px;background:yellow;"></div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I just wasted hours of my life using Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.5 & adjusting some of the snippets above. The class names have changed & the display method on some elements is flexbox so the image would not resize perspective (responsive) to window width. Do yourself a favour & wait for the official release.
If you enjoy a challenge I can at least save you some time. This works (fading carousel slides) in Chrome. Have not tested other browsers.

```
.carousel-item.active,
.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev
{
    /*SET IN BS AS FLEXBOX. SO PERSPECTIVE SCALE DID NOT WORK*/
    display:block;
}


.carousel-inner>.carousel-item>a>img,
.carousel-inner>.carousel-item>img,
.img-responsive
{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .carousel-item {
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity;
    -o-transition-property: opacity;
    -ms-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item,
.carousel-inner .active.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-inner .active.carousel-item-right
{
    opacity:0;
}

.carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-previous.carousel-item-right
{
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-item.active,
.active.carousel-item-left,
.active.carousel-item-prev,
.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right
{
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

[image: Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.5 fade transition]I also grabbed the classes from the BS JS file:

```
var ClassName = {
    CAROUSEL: 'carousel',
    ACTIVE: 'active',
    SLIDE: 'slide',
    RIGHT: 'carousel-item-right',
    LEFT: 'carousel-item-left',
    NEXT: 'carousel-item-next',
    PREV: 'carousel-item-prev',
    ITEM: 'carousel-item'
  };
```

**UPDATE EDIT 4.0.0-beta.2 5th December 2017:**

```
.carousel-item {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.6s ease !important; 
}

.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev {
    left: 0 !important;
}

.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
}

@supports ((-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d) or (transform-style: preserve-3d)) {
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
    }
}

.carousel-item-next,
.active.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
}

@supports ((-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d) or (transform-style: preserve-3d)) {
    .carousel-item-next,
    .active.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
    }
}

.carousel-item-prev,
.active.carousel-item-left {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
}

@supports ((-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d) or (transform-style: preserve-3d)) {
    .carousel-item-prev,
    .active.carousel-item-left {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
    }
}

// THE FIX
.carousel-inner .carousel-item,
.carousel-inner .active.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-inner .active.carousel-item-right
{
    opacity:0;
}

.carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right
{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

You may be able to trim some of the fat out this further? Working in FF, Chrome & Safari (IE/Edge untested).

Comment: Good work, Kerry7777. This CSS seems to still be working in Alpha 6.

Comment: FYI, this does not seem to work with Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta

Comment: I had trouble recently as well with latest BS version. They may have a changed class names again or reworked style rules? So answer above may no longer work?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, its work on my bootstrap 4 beta carousel

```css
.carousel-fade .carousel-item {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .6s;
    transition-duration: .6s;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity; 
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-fade .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    opacity: 1; 
}

.carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-right {
    opacity: 0; 
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-item-prev,
.carousel-fade .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-prev {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0); 
}

@supports (transform-style: preserve-3d) {
    .carousel-fade .carousel-item-next,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-item-prev,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-item.active,
    .carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-left,
    .carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-prev {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); 
    } 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/7/6107/6381966401_032df5fe1e_b.jpg" alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://saxony-blue.com/data/out/86/5918348-image.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's working in my test build:

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-item {
  position: absolute;  
  display: block;
  transition: opacity .9s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-item.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I also find that `.carousel-fade {background-color: #000000;}` makes the transition look smoother if your items have background images.

In v4-alpha, the carousel system was largely rewritten, so the class and transition targeting in previous answers only works with Bootstrap 3. Here's a snippet from the v4.0.0-alpha.6 build that demonstrates how the Bootstrap team rewrote classes:

```
// CSS3 transforms when supported by the browser
@include if-supports-3d-transforms() {
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
```

Comment: I think that for this to work you need to set a width and height to these elements: `.carousel-fade, .carousel-inner, .carousel-item { width: 100%; height: 100%; }` Can you confirm? This might not be suitable to all needs.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a rather easy solution for **Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta**:

- Stack carousel items using `position: absolute`
- Display carousel items, set opacity to 0
- Set opacity to 1 on the active carousel item

```css
.carousel-fade .carousel-item {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-item.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Fixed height, can be dynamic using JS */
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner,
.carousel-fade .carousel-item {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="carousel carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <div class="carousel-item active" style="background: red">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Item 1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item" style="background: blue">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Item 2</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item" style="background: green">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Item 3</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
  
<!-- jQuery !-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<!-- Popper !-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap !-->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The carousel wrapper element does not inherit the height of its children since the carousel items are absolute positioned. This mean we have to set a fixed height for a pure-CSS solution, though we can easily solve this with some JavaScript:

```
// Set min-height property based on the tallest carousel item.
(function () {
    var $inner = $('.carousel-inner'),
        $items = $('.carousel-item');

    var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null,
        $items.map(function() {
            return $(this).outerHeight();
        })
    );

    $inner
        .add($items)
        .css('min-height', maxHeight);
})();
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
----
---
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

JS:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 9000,
  pause: false
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the snippet. But fade effect still does not work. Images are now simply replacing each other instantaneously. Is above snippet for bootstrap 4 alpha5 version?

Comment: You can slow down the speed using js. Edited code above.

Comment: I've incorporated above JS, Images are changing slower now, but there is no fade effect. A culprit is somewhere else.

Comment: I've just updated script above to reflect everything as it stands now.